# Make MySQL dump from parts of each table

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I need to export some data from different tables. I tried this query

```
select * into outfile 'C:\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ololo.sql' from db.users where id % 2 = 1;
```

After this query, the SQL file was created. When I use id i in the the same query to export data from other table. Thus, an error happens. I need additional data from the other table. So, the result must be not dump of all database but part of it. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**mysqldump option `--where`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) like this:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --where="id % 2 = 1" db users > C:\Users\User\Desktop\ololo.sql
```

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: oh, thanks, its works. but how to add to this sql file data from other table? i want parts of different tables in one file.